# JIN c++ with springboot (Tomcat ENV->FindClass return null)

Tags: java-native-interface

I'm trying to call a java function by C++. It is working perfectly fine in Eclipse IDE, but when i build war and running in tomcat. I'm able to call C++ function from Springboot application. But unable to call java function from C++. Since It is unable to find the class which i mentioned with package.

Below is my sample code. Is their is anyway to fix this?

my C++ code

```
void myClientEvents::SendEvents(const char* ack) {
    //Get current thread JNIEnv
    JNIEnv * ENV;



    WriteLogFile("Get current thread JNIEnv");


    try {
        WriteLogFile(ack);

        int stat = savedVM->GetEnv((void **)&ENV, JNI_VERSION_1_8);

        WriteLogFile("stat");
        if (stat == JNI_EDETACHED)  //We are on a different thread, attach
        {
            WriteLogFile("We are on a different thread, attach");
            savedVM->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&ENV, NULL);


        }
        if (ENV == NULL)
        {
            WriteLogFile("Cant attach to java, bail");
             //Cant attach to java, bail
        }

        //Get the Listener class reference
        if (saved_listener_instance != NULL) {
            WriteLogFile("Get the Listener class reference");


            jclass listenerClassRef = ENV->FindClass("org/trinity/serviceImpl/CadiAstroServiceImpl");

            if (listenerClassRef==NULL)
            {
                WriteLogFile("Class Not found"); //This line is printing for tomcat
            }

            WriteLogFile("Use Listener class reference to load the eventOccurred method");

              //Not moving forward from above log in tomcat
            jmethodID ctor = ENV->GetMethodID(listenerClassRef, "<init>", "()V");

            jobject object = ENV->NewObject(listenerClassRef, ctor);
            //Use Listener class reference to load the eventOccurred method
            jmethodID listenerEventOccured = ENV->GetMethodID(listenerClassRef, "eventOccurred", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");

            WriteLogFile("jmethodID created");

            jstring jstr = ENV->NewStringUTF(ack);

            WriteLogFile("invoke listener eventOccurred");
            //invoke listener eventOccurred
            ENV->CallVoidMethod(object, listenerEventOccured, jstr);

            ENV->DeleteLocalRef(jstr);
            ENV->DeleteLocalRef(object);
            ENV->DeleteLocalRef(listenerClassRef);
        }
        else {
            WriteLogFile("Error getting class");
        }
    }
    catch (const char* msg) {

        WriteLogFile(msg);
    }
}
```

my java method in mentioned class

```
public void eventOccurred(String info) {

        System.out.println(info);

    }
```

Comment: Your new thread will probably use the system ClassLoader, as opposed to the one that is installed by Spring. Can you stash a reference to the active ClassLoader for your Spring boot project somewhere (as part of startup) and retrieve it in your new C++ thread? If you cannot figure it out you will need to provide us with more architectural details (who creates the C++ thread and when? What communication do you need between C++ and Java?)

Comment: thanks @Botje. I figured out , by passing the class object to C++  at startup of spring (as a thread) and keeping that reference in C++ for future call from C++ to Java.

Comment: I suggest you summarize your solution in an answer so others can find it.